# Injection moulding

Tags: materials, material-science

What are some examples of real polymer products that can be be produced by injection moulding ? I thought plastic bottles may be one but I think that is done mainly using injection blow moulding

Comment: Plastic bottles are made by blowing air into a small tube called a "Preform". The Preform is injection moulded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cell phone housings and trim, Lego blocks and all other similar types of plastic toys, camera housings, plates, bowls, and dishes of plastic as well as plastic knives, forks and spoons, automobile dashboards, PC and tablet housings, refrigerator drawers, plumbing pipe, fittings, fixtures and sinks, electrical enclosures and conduit fitments, booster seats for children, just to name a few.

Comment: I think you've just done someone's homework.

Comment: It’s not a homework question I was just generally interested as my materials module consists of different manufacturing processes so was just curious what could be created by this.